# SocketIO client + Bluebird hangs in node

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, promise, bluebird

I am trying to wrap SocketIO in a Bluebird promise. The first function `openSocket` takes some parameters, opens a socket, and `resolve`s the promise on the `connect` event.

```
function openSocket(options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        var socket = io(...);

        socket.once('connect', function() {
            console.log("socket: connected");
            resolve(socket);
        });

    });
}
```

Then I close the socket in the same manner, `resolve`ing on the `disconnect` event.

```
function closeSocket(socket) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        socket.once('disconnect', function() {
            console.log("socket: closed");
            resolve();
        });
        socket.close();
    });
}
```

And I have a short promise chain.

```
openSocket(options)
    .then(closeSocket)
    .then(function() {
        console.log("promise chain done");
    })
;
```

The program behaves as expected, EXCEPT **it hangs after printing "promise chain done" for about a minute.**

`strace` says it is polling on fd 5, but I am not sure why?

```
epoll_wait(5, [{EPOLLIN, {u32=12, u64=12}}], 1024, -1) = 1
```

[Here](https://pastebin.com/Yn8sQhTn) is the whole script.

**Edit:** Changed code to not mutate the promise. Mutating the promise was not the problem in this case.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "It hangs" ?

Comment: The program does not terminate after printing "promise chain done". Actually it does terminate, but a minute later. I don't know what it is waiting on.